# Replace all lines containing a certain character with elements from a list, iterating through each element for each line in input

Tags: python

Ok so I have an input file which contains a number of lines that I would like to replace with a different line (using python). For example, the first occurrence of a line containing H in the input file is replaced by the first line of another file (call it x), the second occurrence of a line containing H in the input file is replaced by the second line of the x file and so on. The number of occurrences of lines containing H is the same as the number of lines in the other file (x). This is what I have so far:

```
original = open('PROJECT-pos-1.xyz', 'r')
output = open('output.txt', 'w')
list1 = open('H.txt', 'r')

terms = list1.readlines()



text = original.read()

for term in terms:
        text = text.replace('H', term, 1)

    output.write(text)

original.close()
output.close()
list1.close()
```

In this example H.txt is the file containing a list of replacements and the POSITION file is the file containing the lines to be replaced. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: what do you do if there is insufficient terms to replace the original ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two obvious ways of doing this:

**method 1**:
read the contents of file H as a list and then keep taking the first element of the list `H[0]` whilst reducing the list with `H.pop(0)`.

**method 2**:
similar to method 1. read the contents of file H as a list and then have a counter `i` which increases with each replacement such that you call `H[i]`.

I would prefer method 2...

Here is an example (with lists and not files):

```py
input = ['Hello', 'World', 'How', "Are", "You"]
terms = ['dog', 'cat', 'mouse']
output = []

print('input:', input)

i = 0
for w in input:
    # loop through the input
    if w[0]=='H':
        output.append(terms[i])
        i = i + 1
        if i >= len(terms):
            # reset counter if not enough terms
            i = 0
    else:
        output.append(w)

print('output:', output)
```

result:

```
input: ['Hello', 'World', 'How', 'Are', 'You']
output: ['dog', 'World', 'cat', 'Are', 'You']
```

It is left for the OP to modify this from lists to the file readlines.

Comment: you are welcome.  it was an interesting question to answer.  please do accept and upvote if it was helpful to you.